# LiquidInf jar files

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I have an allotted project which uses LiquidInf. 
`import com.birosoft.liquid.LiquidLookAndFeel;`
Tried searching for downloading jar file but could not get it.
Any help who knows where exactly we get these jar files.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a convention for naming packages, first goes domain name then company name, then goes project's name so in your case it'll be `birosoft.com` so you may try to go to their website and look for a project named `liquid` and look for packages it provide.